# How to reset a password field when username field is cleared?

Tags: javascript

I have login page. When I clear username,  the password is still in the password textfield, it is not cleared.

> ```
> User Name: ________
>
> Password:  ********
> ```

Can you help how to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to post some code, we can't help you unless we know what the problem is. Try replicating the problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and post the link in your question.

Comment: You can change `<input name="username" value=" "/>` with empty space, so the browser won't automatically fill in the remembered username and password, if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen to changes to the `username` field (bind a `change` or `keyup` or `input` event handler). When the value of the field is an empty string, set the value of the password field to an empty string.

Example:

```
document.getElementById('usernameField').onchange = function() {
     if(this.value === '') {
         document.getElementById('passwordField').value = '';
     }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b36Cu/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="password" id="pw" value="" />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('pw').value = '';
```